# How to get a YouTube thumbnail from a YouTube iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

For instance I have a blog post that has the following `iframe`.

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1sIWez9HAbA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I extract the thumbnail from this `iframe`?

Comment: You can also change the thumbnails qualities. Eg. Default
http://img.youtube.com/vi/insert-youtube-video-id-here/default.jpg High Quality Thumbnail
http://img.youtube.com/vi/insert-youtube-video-id-here/hqdefault.jpg Medium Quality
http://img.youtube.com/vi/insert-youtube-video-id-here/mqdefault.jpg Standard Definition
http://img.youtube.com/vi/insert-youtube-video-id-here/sddefault.jpg Maximum Resolution
http://img.youtube.com/vi/insert-youtube-video-id-here/maxresdefault.jpg Font and more info: https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/how-to-get-a-youtube-videos-thumbnail-image-in-high-quality

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**YouTube thumbnails**

YouTube thumbnails can be found in this standard path:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/[thumbnail-number].jpg
```

- `[video-id]` is the YouTube video ID, e.g. `1sIWez9HAbA`.
- `[thumbnail-number]` is the number of the thumbnail of the 4 each
  video usually has, e.g. `0`.

**Getting the thumbnail from an iframe**

So, based on the `iframe`'s `src` attribute you may construct the URL of the thumbnail directly.

For example, using jQuery:

```
var iframe           = $('iframe:first');
var iframe_src       = iframe.attr('src');
var youtube_video_id = iframe_src.match(/youtube\.com.*(\?v=|\/embed\/)(.{11})/).pop();

if (youtube_video_id.length == 11) {
    var video_thumbnail = $('<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/'+youtube_video_id+'/0.jpg">');
    $(body).append(video_thumbnail);
}
```

Note this example checks the URL of the `iframe` for a valid YouTube video ID and assumes it to be 11 characters long, which is the de facto standard.

### See [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/rK8c4/)

Comment: I want to know why your used .pop()

Comment: Updated the answer to more accurately match the video ID in the `iframe`'s URL. In this instance, the `.pop()` method returns the last group match of the regular expression - the video ID.

Comment: You just saved me hours. I was trying to scrape the page for the progress images that pop up when you hover over the time progress bar since I couldn't find any thumbnail images hidden in the page when you're watching a video. Wasn't working nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 52):

**Get Youtube thumbnail images using below urls**

**Low quality**

```
 https://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/sddefault.jpg
```

**medium quality**

```
 https://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/mqdefault.jpg
```

**High quality**

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/hqdefault.jpg
```

**maximum resolution**

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video-id]/maxresdefault.jpg
```

example: https://img.youtube.com/vi/OYr-KPboPDw/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: Some videos like this one [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEEUOiTgJL0&list=RDyqDTgqbQm-0&index=12) 
**don't have max res**, how can you check for that?

Answer (score 6):

This function work with all types of youtube links & domains such as 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZKW2Hq2fks

https://youtu.be/WZKW2Hq2fks

[https://www.youtube.com/embed/WZKW2Hq2fks](https://www.youtube.com/embed/WZKW2Hq2fks%C2%A0)

https://youtu.be/WZKW2Hq2fks?t=66

And you can get the quality you want.

To use it:

```
// quality options: low, medium, high, max | default is max.
var thumbnail = get_youtube_thumbnail('https://youtu.be/WZKW2Hq2fks', 'max');
console.log(thumbnail);
```

---

```
function get_youtube_thumbnail(url, quality){
    if(url){
        var video_id, thumbnail, result;
        if(result = url.match(/youtube\.com.*(\?v=|\/embed\/)(.{11})/))
        {
            video_id = result.pop();
        }
        else if(result = url.match(/youtu.be\/(.{11})/))
        {
            video_id = result.pop();
        }

        if(video_id){
            if(typeof quality == "undefined"){
                quality = 'high';
            }
        
            var quality_key = 'maxresdefault'; // Max quality
            if(quality == 'low'){
                quality_key = 'sddefault';
            }else if(quality == 'medium'){
                quality_key = 'mqdefault';
            } else if (quality == 'high') {
                quality_key = 'hqdefault';
            }

            var thumbnail = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+video_id+"/"+quality_key+".jpg";
            return thumbnail;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```