# What is the best way to load many youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I made a site displaying many youbute videos. If I load all of them at the same time then the site is too slow.

So I load them by inserting rows into a table with Math.min(1ms * 5^row_number, 500ms) delay between each row. Here is what my table looks like. The videos are embedded via iframes.

```
video_11 video_12 (loads at 1ms)
video_21 video_22 (loads at 5ms)
video_31 video_32 (25 ms)
video_41 video_42 (125 ms)
video_51 video_52 (500 ms)
video_61 video_62 (500 ms)
```

It looks kind of choppy, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't load the videos themselves.  That is a waste of bandwidth.

Why not grab a [sceenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681788/how-to-get-a-youtube-thumbnail-from-a-youtube-iframe) instead?

Load a few videos if you want, and only load the rest on demand.

Also, be careful, the more videos you have being loaded, the more buffering you are likely to be doing...

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work. How do we load the video after a thumbnail is clicked? nvm, i see it in the jsfiddle. I don't understand how it works but I can figure it out.

Comment: Possibly the same way that you are loading your own videos right now.  Create a javascript / JQuery / AJAX function that when you click a particular image, will _replace_ the content of the cell with the video you want.